# Matplotlib Bar-plot Frequency and Percentages together

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart

I'm trying to display a barplot that shows values and percentage on the left and right respectfully. I tried myself but I couldn't quite get it. I want to make sure the value and percentage have the same number of labels to simplify the graph. I'm using pyplot module.

[image]
My failed attempt

Comment: What does your data look like? What have you done so far?

Comment: Not much, just a little bit of EDA. I want to generate some interesting graphs while I'm exploring. This is where I got the data. https://www.kaggle.com/kemical/kickstarter-projects